# Android: onActivityResult() is not calling for startActivityForResult

Tags: android, android-activity

I have an Activity named `Main`. I am calling another activity `Sub` from this `Main` activity using `startActivityForResult()`. And I want to take the result of this `Sub` activity using `onActivityResult()` function.

I can call the `Sub` activity. But when return from `Sub` activity, it is not calling `onActivityResult()` function. So I can't get the result of the `Sub` activity.

Actually my `Main` activity is starting from `MainGroup` activity by using `startActivity()` function, which extends `ActivityGroup`.

Is there any way to take the activity result without calling `onActivityResult()` ?

### Edited

Actually I am calling an activity for PayPal Preapprovals. And the activity Which I am calling is on the PayPla library (.jar file). So I can't modify that activity. And when I am implemented this in another application without ActivityGroup, this is working fine

Please help me..

Thank You...

Comment: your child activity should finish to return result and have to call setResult(int) to set result.

Comment: as @om252345 points out, how are you returning from your `Sub` activity?  Can you post the code you use to set the result and finish the activity?

Comment: Actually I am calling an activity for PayPal Preapprovals. And the activity Which I am calling is on the PayPla library (.jar file). So I can't modify that activity. And when I am implemented this in another application without ActivityGroup, this is working fine

Answer (score 1):

to get the `onActivityResult()` method called, you have to ensure that the **requestCode** match the **requestCode** (e.g here **YOUR_REQUEST_CODE**) used in the PreapprovalIntent:

```
  Intent preapproveIntent = PayPal.getInstance().preapprove(
      preapproval, getBaseContext());
  preapproveIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  startActivityForResult(preapproveIntent, YOUR_REQUEST_CODE);
```

so in your onActivityResult() you should have something like:

```
@Override
  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    switch (resultCode) {
      case Activity.RESULT_OK:
        if (requestCode == YOUR_REQUEST_CODE) {
          Log.i("RESULT", "IT WORKS");
        }
        break;

      default:
        break;
    }
  }
```

it should work, but I had an issue with the Activity results actually: instead of calling **Activity.RESULT_OK**, my code invokes **Activity.RESULT_CANCELED** in `onActivityResult()`. Which is really weird since I am sure my preapproval process works. It is even weird since the `onActivityResult()` code is invoked as soon as the PayPal Activity is displayed.

sorry to tell you this, but PayPals' API and documentation is a mess. If some of you had the same issue, please let me know how you solved it (if you solved it ;-))

Answer (score 0):

i think you are doing really wrong imple.if you want to get result of sub than you have to write startActivityForResult() for sub activity and and get activity result from main